# How to validate a regex expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, elasticsearch

I have a user form which gives users ability to enter regex and submit to server. Server side validation for these regexes are present for existing user, but I need javascript regex expression validation to prompt user as soon as a user is done entering his regex expression.

Some example regex:

```
(.*?)_(.*?)_.*_(INS|UPD|DEL|UPSERT)$    -- CORRECT
^Schedule_(.a*)                         -- CORRECT
(IP(.*?)_(.*?)_.*_(INS|UPD|DEL|UPSERT)$ -- WRONG
```

**Note**: Regex will be run on server side (Elasticsearch)

Comment: Are those regexes going to be run in the browser or not? Basically, what do you consider valid regex - is JS regex valid? Perl? Is there a limitation on the grammar used, say, can you have backreferences or lookarounds?

Comment: @vlaz: These regexes will not run in browser. It is submitted to server (java) and in turn given to elasticsearch query to get result. So [elasticsearch regex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) should be valid.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what elasticsearch consideres valid or not but if you have serve-rside validation, can you just translate it to JS? It may need some restructuring but I imagine it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `try/catch` and the `RegExp` constructor you can trace whether it is valid `Regex` or not. Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var isValid = true;
try {
  new RegExp("(.*?)_(.*?)_.*_(INS|UPD|DEL|UPSERT)$");
} catch(e) {
  isValid = false;
}

if(!isValid) alert("This is invalid regular expression");
else alert("This is valid regular expression");
```